# Identify most frequent row from matrix

Tags: r

Lets say I have a matrix:

```
set.seed(12)    
mat<-replicate(3, sample(c(0,1),5,replace=T))
```

I would like to see if any of the rows are identical, and if they are I would like to return the row that occurs most frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> (mat <- matrix(c(rep(c(0,1),3),rep(c(1,0),2)),5, byrow=TRUE))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    1    0
[5,]    1    0
```

do get the row:

```
while(anyDuplicated(mat)>0) {
    mat <- mat[duplicated(mat),]
    if (class(mat)=="numeric") break
}
```

Result:

```
> mat
[1] 0 1
```

Comment: this would be great. the only thing is it breaks if there are no duplicates. can that condition be incoporated?

Comment: Edited the loop. Please try again

Comment: great! final thing can I instead of break assign some value for example 99? I tried replacing break with mat<-99, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(150481)
mat<-replicate(3, sample(c(0,1),100,replace=T))
mat

rows <- c()
for (row.i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  current.row <- mat[row.i,]
  row.as.char <- paste(current.row, collapse = " ")
  rows <- c(rows, row.as.char)
}

max.row <- sort(table(rows), decreasing = T)[1]
as.numeric(strsplit(names(max.row), " ")[[1]])

[1] 0 0 1
```

Careful though, this only returns ONE row that occurs most frequently. If there is more than one row sharing first place, only one will be returned. If you want the frequency table of rows, just do

`sort(table(rows), decreasing = T)`